# Classification type of equilibrium point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the system of differential equations:

\begin{align*}
x'&=-x+y\\
y'&=x-y
\end{align*}

The null cline for both equations is $y=x$, so every point on the line $y=x$ is an equilibrium point.

Does anyone know what they call this type of equilibrium point?

Thanks.

D.

Comment: a degenerate equilibrium (the matrix is singular).

Comment: These are called nonisolated equilibria. Degenerate equilibrium is a much more general term.

Answer (score 1):

This is a singular matrix and this type of equilibrium has no special name.

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1 = 0, ~ \lambda_2 = -2$.

We can solve this system and arrive at:

$$ x(t)=\frac{1}{2} c_1 \left(e^{2 t}+1\right) e^{-2 t}+\frac{1}{2} c_2 \left(e^{2 t}-1\right) e^{-2 t} \\ y(t)=\frac{1}{2} c_1 \left(e^{2 t}-1\right) e^{-2 t}+\frac{1}{2} c_2 \left(e^{2 t}+1\right) e^{-2 t}$$

You can parametrically plot these equations.

We can also plot a phase portrait and arrive at (notice the null-cline line at $y=x$):

[image]